# Racket - writing a function to display a distribution

Tags: racket

I'm just a beginner in racket and I'm trying to write a function that takes a distribution and displays a graphical representation of the histogram. Is anyone able to help me out?

Comment: See examples in the docs: http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/dist_dist-objects.html?q=Math

Comment: Yes. Please read [How to design programs](http://www.htdp.org/). How to do graphical stuff starts in the end of section 22. Good luck!